# Working of Prefix Adder

Tags: adder, system-verilog

[image: brent Kung adder]

I am trying to understand the working of Brent Kung adder, but I have not been able to.
All that I see in tutorials is just the figure above for carry generation. Can anybody explain it to me with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic Brent-Kung recursion is shown in stages 1 and 5 in your figure. Stage 1 performs a dot operation (in terms of an adder, the prefix computation structure itself is general) of pairs 0-1, 2-3, 4-5 and so on. These outputs are connected to an 8-bit (half length) prefix structure, in this case stages 2-4, while stage 5 connects the odd inputs with the nearby output of the half length prefix structure (1-2, 3-4, and so on)

For a "proper" Brent-Kung adder, the 8-bit prefix structure in stages 2-4 should be decomposed similarly, with stage 2 connecting 1-3, 5-7, 9-11, and 13-15, stage 3 being a 4-bit prefix structure operating on line 3, 7, 11, and 15, while stage 4 connects the outputs with the bypassed signals as 3-5, 7-9, and 11-13.

The 4-bit can then be decomposed again into 3-7 and 11-15 with these fed into a 2-bit prefix structure (which can not be decomposed again) connecting 7-11 at the output.

Note that in your figure stages 2-4 does not form a Brent-Kung prefix structure, but another 8-bit prefix structure.